# Why doesn't this function work? It is returning, "undefined"!

Tags: javascript

## Javascript

```
function grabById(id, object, newValue) {
    document.getElementById(id).object = newValue;
}
```

## HTML

```
<p id="p">Hi!</p>
```

## Console

I type in the console:

```
grabById("p","innerHTML","New value for innerHTML")
```

## Result

The console spits back at me with `undefined`

And nothing happens!

Comment: You forgot to put a `return` statement in your function.

Comment: I think you just reinvented the wheel : your function will help you to do in 1 line the same thing you could do in... 1 line of javascript anyway.

Comment: What about grabById('p','style.color','red'); Its not working! @Bartdude

Comment: No wonder it's not working, `p` isn't an id (at least I hope so) , it's a tag name. But seriously, if that code is not only for example, you're doing throiugh a function what can be achieved with javascript native functions with probably even a few characters less. The fact that your function is only 1 line should already make you realize how useless it is.

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to use bracket notation

```
function grabById(id, object, newValue) {
    document.getElementById(id)[object] = newValue;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BYCLJ/)

and it changes the html of an element, it does not return anything, and I see no reason why it should, but based on the name maybe it's supposed to return the element ?

```
function grabById(id, object, newValue) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id)
    elem[object] = newValue;
    return elem;
}
```

Comment: Thank You!Can you explain why I have to use bracket notation?

Comment: because dot notation doesn't interpret variables

Comment: @user3516029 - Read this -> **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators**